# Persistent volume Kubernetes on Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Redis pod on my Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud. I have built PV and the claim.

```
   
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: redis-pv
 labels:
   type: local
spec:
 storageClassName: manual
 capacity:
   storage: my-size 
 accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
 hostPath:
   path: "/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 labels:
   app: postgres
 name: redis-pv-claim
spec:
 storageClassName: manual
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: my size 
I also mounted it in my deployment.yaml

volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /data
       name: redis-pv-claim
   volumes:
   - name: redis-pv-claim
     persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: redis-pv-claim
```

I can't see any error while running describe pod

```
Volumes:
 redis-pv-claim:
   Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
   ClaimName:  redis-pv-claim
   ReadOnly:   false
```

But it just can't save any key. After every deployment, the "/data" folder is just empty.

My NFS is active now but i still cant keep data .

Describe pvc

```
Namespace:     my namespace 
StorageClass:  nfs-client
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-5d278b27-a51e-4262-8c1b-68b290b21fc3
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
              pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
              volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: nfs-client
              volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: cluster.local/ext1-nfs-client-provisioner
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1Gi
Access Modes:  RWX
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    my grafana pod
Events:        <none>
```

Describe pod gives me an error though.

```
Warning  FailedMount  18m   kubelet, gke-devcluster-pool-1-36e6a393-rg7d  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-5d278b27-a51e-4262-8c1b-68b290b21fc3" : mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/8f7b6630-ed9b-427a-9ada-b75e1805ed60/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-5d278b27-a51e-4262-8c1b-68b290b21fc3 --scope -- /
home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/mounter mount -t nfs 192.168.1.21:/mnt/nfs/development-test-claim-pvc-5d278b27-a51e-4262-8c1b-68b290b21fc3 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/8f7b6630-ed9b-427a-9ada-b75e1805ed60
/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-5d278b27-a51e-4262-8c1b-68b290b21fc3
Output: Running scope as unit: run-ra5925a8488ef436897bd44d526c57841.scope
Mount failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: chroot
```

Comment: By looking at first YAML , you are using hostpath volume which is only retained if you are on the same node after each deployment. You are not using NFS in redis deployment so the two issue seems unrelated. Also which pod have you described and your lables show postgres , please try to re describe your question to make more sense.

Comment: Please check [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and clarify your question as @tarun khosla suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Working redis with PV and PVC on GKE

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis  
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redislabs/rejson
          args: ["--requirepass", "password", "--appendonly", "no", "--loadmodule", "/usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: .50
              memory: 1500Mi
            requests:
              cpu: .25
              memory: 1000Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-volume
              mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

you can update image in this stateful sets as per need.